# Which character set should I use for Traditional and Simplified Chinese in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I am using the newest MYSQL version (5.7.4 I think), and my web app will support CJK language, especially Traditional and Simplified Chinese. I tried to google the answer, but they seem to use separate character sets (big 5 and gbk). Which specific character set should I use if I want to support CJK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utf8 handles simplified and traditional Chinese (as well as Korean and Japanese).